# Bootstrap Input and Select in a table slightly off

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3 and I have a table with some inputs and selects.

The inputs are about 1px lower than the select:

[image]

and no matter what I do I cant seem to get them to line up on the same level.

This rows HTML is like so:

```
<tr id="other-license-row-new" data-other-license-id="-1">
    <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#" class="btn-save-attach" data-on-upload="other-license">Attach File</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select class="form-control other-license-class">
            <option>C - Car</option>
            <option>LR - Light Rigid</option>
            <option>MR - Medium Rigid</option>
            <option>HR - Heavy Rigid</option>
            <option>HC - Heavy Combination</option>
            <option>MC - Multi Combination</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td class="expiry-date-row">
                <input type="text" class="form-control other-license-expiryDate date-picker" data-position="top left">
    </td>
    <td>
            <select type="text" class="other-license-state form-control">
                <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
                <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
                <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
                <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
                <option value="SA">SA</option>
                <option value="WA">WA</option>
                <option value="NT">NT</option>
                <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
            </select>
    </td>
    <td>
            <input type="text" class="other-license-number form-control">
    </td>
    <td class="action-column">
       ...dropdown button html removed for brevity...
    </td>
</tr>
```

I would like to know how I can align the inputs and select so it doesnt have he 1px difference.

I have tried:

select, input{
 vertical-align: middle; //as well as all options in web inspector
}

Comment: Have you tried `vertical-align` ?

Comment: try `vertical-align: middle || top ...`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align